# How to make OS X Cocoa application load custom frameworks from the folder it resides in?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, frameworks

By default all frameworks are being loaded from **~/Library/Frameworks** and that's fine for development purposes, however for deployment purposes I need to find a way to load all my linked custom frameworks from the folder with the application folder or somewhere in the .app folder... Please tell me, how can I do it? Is it possible to solve this problem without loading frameworks manually?

**XCode v4** has an option **deployment location**, but it doesn't seem to be used (I copy compiled frameworks into /Frameworks folder via script in build phase).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you want, but if you simply want to link a framework/lib at any location, double click on your **target** in xcode4, click the plus in the "**Link Binary With Libraries**" Section and choose "**add other...**". If linking is not enough and you need to copy stuff inside your .app folder simply also add that lib to the "**Copy Bundle Resource**" phase. (or add an extra copy phase for that)

Comment: Forgive me for not being clear... You see, my frameworks are already linked with my Cocoa application and they are being copied to the /Frameworks folder, because Cocoa applications load them from this stupid folder... I don't want my users to install my application this way (for many reasons) and so I need to find a way to make my Cocoa application load the linked frameworks from the same folder it resides in (Windows-style - loading dll's from the same folder the program is in.). And I have no idea how to do this...

Comment: well I am pretty sure that you'd simply need to copy the framework into the .app bundle as described above. that should give you the desired behaviour (i.e. no need that the framework is installed in the /Frameworks folder. Check out this link http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html for a detailed explanation, see: Embedding a Private Framework in Your Application Bundle

Comment: Thanks, moka, that article is just what I was looking for!